# QTP click on winbutton with failure

Tags: click, qtp

I'm working on QTP with web-adding. There are some buttons in type "Winbutton" on the page. The "click" action on most of the buttons works very well except one. In fact this winbutton is a checkbox. But I don't know why it is recognized as Winbutton. But when click on it, it just gets focused but not really clicked. The checkbox is not checked. So I would like to know if anyone met the similar problem before and if anyone knows how to solve this.

Many thanks in adavance

Allen

[image: The Winbutton]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/B5eLZ.png

[image: Description]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZDwl.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't usually get `WinButton` in web pages. Is the QTP hierarchy `Browser.Page.WinButton`? If so the control is probably really a .NET or ActiveX control. Make sure that you have the .NET and ActiveX addins loaded when you launch QTP.

Do you have a public site that you can point to in order to see this problem?

---

**Edit:** As seen in the comments to this answer the control was actually a Java control.

Comment: Yes, the hierarchy is like that. And sorry, I don't have a public site. The page is a little different from the others, exsited the objects with the classes such as SunAwtCanvas, etc. I attach the descriptions to this thread

Comment: @allenzzzxd that sounds like a Java control, try loading the Java addin.